# AWS SWF Flow does the activity start to close timeout include activity retries?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, registration, amazon-swf

I'm trying to configure one of my SWF activities using the Flow framework for java and I can't find any documentation about whether the StartToClose timeout is only for a single activity attempt or for all of the retry attempts for that activity.

Here is the configuration for my activity:

```
@Activity(name = "WaitForExternalTaskToFinish", version = "1.0")
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(
        defaultTaskScheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds = 60,
        defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 60)
@ExponentialRetry(
        initialRetryIntervalSeconds = 60,
        maximumRetryIntervalSeconds = 300,
        retryExpirationSeconds = 7200,
        exceptionsToRetry = IllegalStateException.class)
boolean waitForExternalTaskToFinish(long externalTaskId);
```

I'm trying to get this activity that is expected to take a very short execution time (eg. 5 sec) but if the activity fails then keep retrying the activity to for 2 hours.

- Will this configuration do what I want?
- Do I need to change defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds to 7200?
- If I need to change defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds to 7200, then how do I get the activity to fail if the execution of a single activity attempt is "too long" (eg. 100 sec)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StartToClose timeout is for a single activity attempt. Exponential retry is not natively supported by SWF backend and is currently implemented as a decider logic. If you are curious [here is](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/aspectj/ExponentialRetryAspect.java) the ExponentialRetry AspectJ aspect implementation.

Answering your questions:

1. Yes it will.
2. No.